# Simple REST endpoints authentication

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-security

I am learning how secure my endpoints, but everything i searched for contains pretty complicated examples, that didn't really answerd my question, and for now, just for the sake of this example project, i was looking for something simple.

My current solution is to make endpoints return like this:

```
return authenticate(request.headers) ? cityService.getCity() : utils.unauthenticatedResponse();
```

Where authenticate(request.headers) checks for token in header.
The thing i want to improve is to have that authenticate method run before every request to my endpoints (aside from login and register), so i can just return cityService.getCity(), and i won't have to make that check every time.

Will appreciate every answers, but please make it easy yo understand, since i am just a beginner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you need to run the `authenticate` method before every request, you need to implement a `Filter`. It's pretty straightforward and you can get the steps and  template to implement a filter [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-add-filter).

Every request to an endpoint will first pass through the filter (this is configurable), where you can have the `authenticate` method and then allow it further accordingly.

For starters, you can implement a filter like below:

```
@Component
public class AuthFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter
      ServletRequest request, 
      ServletResponse response, 
      FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        if(authenticate(req.getHeaders)){
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        } else {
            //else logic, ie throw some exception in case authenticate returns false
        }
    }

}
```

The advantages that this provides are :

- You can implement multiple filters
- You can provide Order/priority to filters
- You can configure which endpoints need to pass through the filter and which ones do not.

Comment: Thanks so much!
By the way, would that also by the proper way to secure real production application, or do you need to use something more complicated?

Comment: @koxmaxiums Production grade applications can be secured either by implementing custom filters like above, and having an own implementation of checking the token, or by using something like Spring security which provides predefined tools to authenticate which can be used along with custom auth.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ContainerRequestFilter](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerRequestFilter.html) (if you are using Spring/Tomcat)

Every request coming to the server will go through this filter, so you can implement your code in it.

Comment: And ContainerRequesrFilter can have a priority annotation as well. Making sure you can control when the filter is invoked